# Exposing SQL Server database to internet

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a POS application that is used by a business. The application has a SQL Server backend and there’s a local machine that acts as a server for the DB. The other computers within the office connect to this server. This happens over TCP/IP. I am wondering if it is possible and/or how difficult it would be to expose this database and allow read access to an offsite application. Essentially I want to be able to pull data from a local database into AWS on a regular automated schedule. If anyone has any ideas that could help point me in the right direction, that would be great. This is not an application I’m a developer of, so I don’t have access to the application code or anything like that. I guess what it boils down to would be the equivalent of an off-site backup. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't expose your database to the internet. Put it behind a firewall and set up a VPN which can then be used to connect to it.

Comment: Expose probably was the wrong word. I guess what I’m really looking to do is create offsite backups automatically. I would also need to be able to remotely configure the access. I suppose I could remotely configure a VPN, but I would need to be able to automatically connect to the VPN, access the DB and create the backup on an ongoing basis without any user interaction.

Comment: You could set up a site to site VPN that is always active, that way you don't have to connect/disconnect all of the time.

Comment: You’re trying to have SQL Server push backups to some remote place? Why does a user have to connect to it and intervene? Just schedule the backups, then SQL Server just needs access to that location, instead of giving the entire world access to SQL Server. If you need to interact with it and you can’t VPN or add your IP to a firewall’s whitelist then put a simple app in front of it (web app or API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I’m really looking to do is create offsite backups automatically

SQL Server can natively backup to Azure Blob Storage.  See [Backup to URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-2017).

But whatever offsite storage you use, the right solution is for SQL Server (or code running on the local network) to *push* the data out.  Not have code running elsewhere *pull* it out.

That way you don't need to open anything to the internet, or use a VPN.  You just need to open outbound ports, to connect to the internet.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because I believe it would be the best option of those offered. I've since learned that I won't be able to get the credentials to access the database. I'm now looking at pushing a bak file that's created up to S3 and using that to populate an RDS instance.